# handlebar dynamic components render

Tags: templates, components, handlebars.js

i am setting project for dynamic compoenents  in handlebars
where i have multiple compoenents like headers, heros, features, cards etc
i have the patials  and json file
i want render the templates dynamically from json file

```
"header": {
            "template":4,
            "logo": "https://lucide.dev/logo.light.svg",
            "title": "My Website",
            "subtitle": "This is a one-page website",
            "navbar": [
                {
                    "label": "Home",
                    "link": "#home"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Features",
                    "link": "#features"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Pricing",
                    "link": "#pricing"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Contact",
                    "link": "#contact"
                },
                {
                    "label": "About Us",
                    "link": "#about-us"
                }
            ]
        },
```

there template:4
then it render header4.handlebars

```
 {{#with (concat "Headers/Header" json.websiteContent.header.template)}}
    {{> this headerContent=json.websiteContent.header colorSchema=json.colorSchema}}
    {{/with}}
```

i was with this but having problem with concat

having any solution for select template from json file

Comment: Is `concat` a custom helper that _you_ have created?